# RandomForestClassifier : binary classification scores

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using sklearn's RandomForestClassifier to build a binary prediction model. As expected, I am getting an array of predictions, consisting of 0's and 1's. However I was wondering if it is possible for me to get a value between 0 and 1 along with the prediction array and set a threshold to tune my model. 
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html, you are using teh predict method to derive the binary response.  If you call predict_proba, you will get an array of probabilities corresponding to the binary response.

Comment: the method returns 2 values per prediction, (which sum up to 1) as min and max, how can I interpret them ?

Comment: The first column is the probability of the positive (or negative, definitely check) outcome, the second column is the probability of the opposite outcome.  So you really only need to use one column.

Comment: The attribute `classes_` tells you which column is which. After you fit your model to the data, just use 
`<RFmodel>.classes_` to see columns to which the classes correspond.